# flutter Infinite Scrolling for ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, infinite-scroll, infinite

I've to use graphql query and I've got data page by page.
so I need to Infinite Scrolling in my list view builder but I don't know how to add num in page.
can anyone help me, please?

this is my query:

```
query homeview(\$moreId: ID!, \$page: Int! ){
    homeview(HM_ID: \$moreId, page: \$page){
    HM_ID
    HM_Type_ID
    HM_Type_Name 
  }
}
""";
```

and this is my variable to pass int number in `page`:
`dynamic pageNum = 0;`

here is the controller :

```
 ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController(  initialScrollOffset: 10,
```

and this is my list view builder:

```
   class MoreEpd extends StatefulWidget {
  final String moreId;
  const MoreEpd({Key? key, required this.moreId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MoreEpdState createState() => _MoreEpdState();
}

class _MoreEpdState extends State<MoreEpd> {
  double pageWidth = 0;
  double pageHeigh = 0;
  dynamic pageNum = 0;

  final String leftArrow = 'assets/icons/left-arrow.svg';
  String getSearchResult = """
 query homeview(\$moreId: ID!, \$page: Int! ){
    homeview(HM_ID: \$moreId, page: \$page){
    HM_ID
    Priority
    Details{
      Ep_ID
      Image
      title
      Pod_title
      
    }
  }
}
""";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pageWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    pageHeigh = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Container(
      child: Query(
        options: QueryOptions(
          document: gql(getSearchResult),
          variables: {'moreId': widget.moreId, 'page': pageNum},
        ),
        builder: (
          QueryResult result, {
          Refetch? refetch,
          FetchMore? fetchMore,
        }) {
          return handleResult(result);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

 
  Widget handleResult(QueryResult result) {
    var data = result.data!['homeview']['Details'] ?? [];
    return Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: data.length ,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: pageWidth * 0.0,
                      right: pageWidth * 0.08,
                      left: pageWidth * 0.08,
                      bottom: pageWidth * 0.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(bottom: pageWidth * 0.060),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(left: pageWidth * 0.01),
                                    child: Container(
                                      // alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                      width: pageWidth * 0.128,
                                      height: pageWidth * 0.128,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                                data[index]['Image'],
                                              )),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(15)),
                                          // color: Colors.redAccent,
                                          border: Border.all(
                                            color: MyColors.lightGrey,
                                            width: 1,
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              width: pageWidth * 0.5,
                                              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                              child: Text(
                                                data[index]['title'],
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                maxLines: 1,
                                                // softWrap: true,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }}
```

can anyone help me please how can I use infinite scrolling to load other pages in my query?

Comment: why do you need infinite scroll? listview.builder will be as big as it needs to fit all data

Comment: because I should pass int num to `page` query and get data from it.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use a `ListView.builder` without specifying the `itemCount` parameter.

Here is the simplest example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Infinite List"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text("$index");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Later, you can enhance this by fetching real data. You could show a 'CircularProgressIndicator' in the last item of the list while waiting for the new data.

```
body: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index < data.length) {
        // Show your info
        return Text("$index");
      } else {
        getMoreData();
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
    itemCount: data.length + 1,
  ),
```

You can see that we trick the list by adding an index, and calling for more data when displaying that final index.

`getMoreData()` would include a call to `setState()` to force a rebuild and to take into account the new data.

Comment: what is getMoreData()? class or method?

Comment: I don't know what I should put in getMoreData . i just want to  `pageNum +=1;` this happen and load more data

Comment: @stysh  it is function  _getMoreData() async {
    final moreItems = await widget.onRequest(items.length);
    if (!mounted) return;

    if (moreItems.isEmpty) {
      setState(() => end = true);
      return;
    }
    setState(() => items = [...items, ...moreItems]);
  }

Comment: @stysh also you can check this tutorial https://dartpad.dev/?id=6ae326a7422736d6011ee1006819b123&null_safety=true . If  it helps then please upvote it

Comment: @lnfostans it's cool but I can't match it with my project. I upload my class in question. Would you please see it and tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here I've created a [flat_list](https://pub.dev/packages/flat_list) widget which has a similar specification as in React Native. Hope the below works.

```
FlatList(
+  loading: loading.value,
+  onEndReached: () async {
+    loading.value = true;
+    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
+    if (context.mounted) {
+      items.value += getMoreData();
+      loading.value = false;
+    }
+  },
  data: items.value,
  buildItem: (item, index) {
    var person = items.value[index];

    return ListItemView(person: person);
  },
),
```